# How to open a text file as a character matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, statistics

I have a .fa file which contains a list of secuences of nucleotids. It is something like this

> AGCTAGAGAGACTAGACTAGA
>
> GATCAGTACATGATCTAGGAT
>
> GATAGTACATGGGGGATAGAC

I need to somehow open the file in python and make a 2-dim array which contains as rows the lines of the .fa file and in each column a letter of the file. Thanks for any help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in having a matrix be a list of lists, you can do it easily with a list comprehension.

```
with open("myfile.fa","rt") as infile:
    matrix = [list(line.strip()) for line in infile.readlines()]
    print matrix
```

If, on the other hand, you would prefer to have a `numpy` matrix (note this requires that you have installed `numpy`):

```
import numpy

with open("myfile.fa","rt") as infile:
    matrix =  numpy.matrix([list(line.strip()) for line in infile.readlines()])
    print matrix
```